# Add if statement in eloquent then join another table

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have some problem with my code.

In my case, i have 2 table. one is table A , table A relation with table B (using foreign not column primary in table B)

and in table A , have some data like :

```
 +----+-------------------+
 | id | transcation_number|
 +----+-------------------+
 | 1  |   TR0919231       | 
 +----+-------------------+
 | 2  |   TR8123844       |
 +----+-------------------+
 | 3  |   RI8482452       | 
 +----+-------------------+
```

table B

```
 +----+------------+---------+
 | id | trx_number | status  |
 +----+------------+---------+
 | 1  | TR0919231  | success |
 +----+------------+---------+
 | 2  | TR8123844  | success |
 +----+------------+---------+
```

in this case, data number 3 is not have relation in table B (This data number starts with RI). data 1 and 2 have relation. and when i want to display it, i want data 3 to still appear but not join to table B. and data 1,2 must join to table B.

like :

```
if tableA has spesific word by 'RI' 
  then not set any query where  
else 
  then set eloquent query where 'status == success' in tableB column.
```

sorry for my bad word and grammar.

Comment: Your model will return null in case of 3rd value if it will not exists in Table B, then what is the concern?

Comment: @jogesh_pi i dont know how implementation in my eloquent

Comment: Can you show the Table B structure with some related data?

Comment: And you are sure that ```RI8482452``` value will / does not exists in the Table B?

Comment: yes, that will not exists in the table B

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can build the model relationship with foreign_key and local_key

```
class TableA extends Model 
{

    public function tableB() {
        // Assuming the trx_number is the foreign_key that will map with 
        // transcation_number local_key
        return $this->hasOne(TableB::class, 'trx_number', 'transcation_number');
    }
}
```

To know more in details please take a look at the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#one-to-one).

Comment: how about query for display it?

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent shouldn't prevent you from getting result A if there isn't a result B.  However, if you want to be extra sure, you can lazy load the relationship instead.

Relation (placed in the tableA.php class): jogesh_pi had this right.

```
public function tableB() {
    return $this->hasOne(TableB::class, 'trx_number', 'transaction_number');
}
```

Lazy load:

```
$result = TableA::get();
$result->load('tableB');
```

Refer to this article for more information: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#lazy-eager-loading

Basically, you will get all the results from table A, and afterward you will tag on table B where there's a match on the relationship.